# Facebook Post Request Not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, coffeescript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I am using the Facebook JavaScript SDK in my web app. The following function will be invoked when I click on a Facebook invite button

```
facebookInvite: (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  FB.ui
    method: "apprequests"
    message: "Become my Buddie"
    filters: [ "app_non_users" ]
    title: "Become my Buddie"
  , (response) ->
    if response and response.request_ids
      $howManyInvites = String(requests).split(",").length
    else
      false
```

Everything seemed to work fine i.e popup appears with my friends list

[image]

However, after clicking on 'send request', I only see a blank screen popup

[image]

Also, the request did not seem to go through at all.

Anything I missed out in my  implementation?

Comment: looks like you missing `requests` variable, shouldn't it be `response.request_ids.split(',')` instead?

Comment: What's the console telling you?

Answer (score 0):

The apprequest dialog only works for canvas apps...